# If Range EntireRow.Hidden

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate your help with following issue I am facing.

I want 3 rows to be hidden unless something is written in a specific cell.
If something is written in the specific cell I want the next row to become unhidden. And so it suppose to continue with the next two cells.

I have written the following code in th module, please guide me on how to solve this (what am I doing wrong?)

```
Sub InsertRow()
    If Range("U6") <> "" Then 
        Rows("7").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("8:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? I see it only hides two rows (8 and 9)...is that it?  Can you please clarify your issue/question?  Or do you need code for if `U6` is empty, then 7, 8, and 9 should be hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but this goes through all used cells in col U and checks rows beneath

```
Public Sub InsertRow()
    Dim targetCol As Range, itm As Range

    Set targetCol = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(21)  'UsedRange starts at A1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False             'Update sheet name and column number

    For Each itm In targetCol.Cells
        itm.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = (Len(itm.Value2) = 0)
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Sub InsertRow()
    Rows("7").EntireRow.Hidden = Range("U6") = ""
    Rows("8:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```